# Objective-C: Automation

Tags: objective-c, automation, automator

**How would one go about achieving one of these two ways for automation?**

1, Have the app check a server directory continuously (or in given intervals) for changes, while it is running, or....

2, automate that app somehow from outside. (I heard an Automator plugin written in XCode might be able to do something like this).

I don't need specific code (not hat it's not appreciated) just general pointers or classes or tips I could use to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you want to look into is the ever-useful [NSTimer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html), combined in your case with for instance [NSURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLRequest_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for the actual fetching.

It might be a good idea to have an option to turn of this continuous checking, as network conditions might not always be amenable to repeated HTTP requests.

Additionally, avoid doing HTTP requests on the main thread, use an asynchronous request or a dedicated thread.

Using Automator is likely counter-productive.